# Using Arrays as Global Variables

Tags: c++, arrays, global-variables

I am trying to use arrays as global variables. It seems that I cannot use a previously initialized variable such as `l` for dimensioning the arrays and I get the following error

error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token.

However, this is possible when I try to use the same thing inside the `main` function.

Can someone explain what is happening here?

```
//  If you move the following lines inside the main function then everything works fine

int l = 3;
int a[l] = {1, 2, 3};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays with global scope or defined as `static` need dimensions known at compile time, and as Neil says, declaring `l` as `const` achieves this.

As a gcc / clang extension, arrays allocated within a function (i.e. allocated on the stack) can have dimensions known only at runtime.  This is not standard however, and (for example) MSVC does not permit it.

Answer (score 1):

Just change l to

```
const int l=3;
```